# Discord.py 2.0 - Handle interactions failed when using same command in parallel

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm currently coding a bot consisting of mini games (one command = one game) which use interaction buttons. I'm having some issues handling the asynchronous aspect of my commands. When multiple users are using the same command at the same time (for example two people playing a maze game with directional buttons), interaction failures tend to occur which affects the running of each instance of the command.

Here is the code structure of the command :

```py
@bot.command(brief="...",help="...")
@commands.cooldown(1, 60*60, commands.BucketType.member)
async def maze(ctx):
    #PostreSQL check
    cur = conn.cursor()
    req = "..."
    cur.execute(req)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    if len(rows)>0 :    
        m = Maze(13,13) #Generate a 13x13 maze board
        brd = m.saveEmojiBoard(True) #str representation of the board (unicode emojis)
        class myButton(ui.Button):
            def __init__(self,label,style):
                super().__init__(label=label,style=style)
                    
            async def callback(self,interaction):
                nonlocal rows
                if interaction.user.id==ctx.author.id  :
                    moved = False                  
                    if  str(self.label)=="\U000025C0":
                        moved = m.left()
                    elif  str(self.label)=="\U000025B2":
                        moved = m.up()
                    elif  str(self.label)=="\U000025BC":
                        moved = m.down()
                    elif  str(self.label)=="\U000025B6":
                        moved = m.right()  
                    if moved: 
                        brd = m.saveEmojiBoard(True) #Update board if position changed
                        await self.view.msg.edit(content=brd)   
                        await interaction.response.defer()     
                        if m.goalreached() : 
                            #Game ends when exit found, then update database
                            req = "..."
                            cur.execute(req)
                            conn.commit()
                            self.view.stop()
                            await ctx.send("...") 
                    else : await interaction.response.defer()                    
                else : await interaction.response.defer()
                        
        class myView(ui.View):   
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__(timeout=120)   
                self.add_item(myButton("\U000025C0",style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary))
                self.add_item(myButton("\U000025B2",style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary))
                self.add_item(myButton("\U000025BC",style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary))
                self.add_item(myButton("\U000025B6",style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary))
                              
            async def on_timeout(self):
                await ctx.send("...")
        
            async def on_error(self,error, item, interaction) :
                print("...")  
                traceback.print_exc()
                
        v = myView()    
        await ctx.send(view=v) 
                           
    else : await ctx.send("...")
```

Thanks if anyone can bring me some help

[Game screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvrTJ.png)

Comment: It is preferable to use non-blocking methods wherever possible. Your database calls are currently blocking (not allowing the bot to respond elsewhere at the same time), there are other Postgresql wrappers such as asyncpg or aiopg that are non-blocking

Comment: Hi, i've changed into asyncpg and ran a couple of tests with other users. It doesn't seem to optimize that much. I often encounter this error: "discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction". It seems like the interaction object disappears during the callback function. Can it be a memory issue?

Comment: Unknown interaction means you are taking too long to respond. Discord gives you 3 seconds to acknowledge the interaction with a response. If you need more time to send the message, you should defer the interaction (await interaction.response.defer()) before you do anything, then respond with the interaction's followup webhook later on.

Comment: Thanks, i've managed to fix the error with defer-followup. It still does have some latency in the bot's response but i think it comes from the host. I used to host on local/Heroku free tier and it was a bit slow to handle 2/3 people on the same game at the same time. I'll need to find an alternative since the free tier is about to get removed

Comment: A paid VPS is definitely the best option, but I'm with you on wanting free tiers and I also am in the process of finding alternatives for Heroku. It seems to me that Fly.io may be a good free option, but it's not as good as Heroku in my opinion, and doesn't compare to options like AWS, DO, GCP.

Comment: Tutorial for hosting a bot on Fly.io (my own): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7Fm7MdZn_E

Comment: I'm now hosting on Vercel and CockroachDB, I had some issues setting Fly.io and understanding its interface. I'll save it for later if I encounter any issue with Vercel, thanks.